# On key press event request.form getting null

Tags: html, internet-explorer, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a login page in classic asp which contains two buttons login and signup . Also i have a submit button which is hidden .On form submit i am checking the 
if request.form(submit) = login

then login steps

else request.form(signup) = signup

it works fine in all browsers but in IE when i hit the enter key it esacpe the request.form(submit) = login and request.form(signup) = signup but when i click on enter button then it works fine . Any idea why i am getting nothing on the request.form(submit) = login .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty basic and fundamental: Internet Explorer does not have "default" submit button. Every browser is free to choose how to behave in case of submitting a form via <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, modern browsers choose the logical way of sending the value of the first submit button (as if it was clicked) while IE, being IE, choose the unfriendly way. No surprise and no way to fix the root of this "problem" unless you happen to write the code for IE.

The only way around this is using JavaScript and *forcing* the browser to choose specific submit button upon pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. For this, first add unique ID to the login button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" id="btnLogin" />
```

Now add `onkeypress` handler to your form tag:

```
<form action="YourPage.asp" method="POST" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode === 13) { document.getElementById('btnLogin').click(); return false; }">
```

This will emulate clicking the login button whenever <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed inside the form.

Only downside of this approach is that if your form contains `<textarea>`, pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in them will also submit the form which is not a good thing. To have them behave as they should behave add this to each of them:

```
<textarea onkeypress="event.cancelBubble = true;">
```

The above will cancel the event from bubbling upwards to the `<form>` keypress event.